# ¿Como mantener datos ingresados en input despues de enviar formulario con javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Buenas quisiera ver si es posible guardar o consercar los datos ingresados en los inputs de un form despues que este sea enviado. Ya que al hacer submit la pagina se refresca entonces, lo que intento es que aunque la pagina se refresque los datos ingresados en el formulario sigan ahi. Vi algo acerca de localStorage pero no logro conseguirlo hasta ahora eh hecho esto:

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type='text' name="server" id="saveServer" />
        <button type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" onclick="save_data()">Save</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function save_data() {
           var input = document.getElementById("saveServer").value;
           var saveInput = localStorage.setItem("input",input);
           var showStorage = localStorage.getItem("save",input);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Entonces no se como podria llegar a guardar los datos del input en localStorage para que aunque se recargue la pagina o se cierre el navegador los datos sigan ahi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permíteme proponerte este fragmento de ejemplo que escribí para tu problema:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Formulario persistente</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="server" id="saveServer"/>
            <button type="submit" value="Save" id="Save">Save</button>
        </form>
        <script>

            let serverInput     = document.getElementById('saveServer');
            let saveButton      = document.getElementById('Save');

            saveButton.addEventListener('click', () =>
            {
                localStorage.setItem('serverValue', serverInput.value);
            });

            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
            {
                let savedServer  = localStorage.getItem('serverValue');

                if (savedServer)
                {
                    serverInput.value = savedServer;
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Básicamente, guardas el valor de tu `<input>` en el `LocalStorage` cuando envías el formulario mediante el `<button>Save</button>` en el evento `click` y lo obtienes cuando el [`DOM`](https://lenguajejs.com/javascript/dom/que-es/) está listo después de recargada la página por el envío del formulario en el evento `DOMContentLoaded`.

**Nota:** No es necesario emplear `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Increible muchas gracias estaba atascado en esto. Muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes manejar con `addEventListener`, ahora haciendolo asi puedes evitar el comportamiento de refresco de la pantalla con `preventDefault()` que trae el evento como tal como ves en el siguiente codigo.

```
<form action="/">
        <input type='text' name="server" id="saveServer" />
        <button type="submit" value="save" id="save">Save</button>
</form>
<script>
   document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const input = document.getElementById("saveServer").value;
            localStorage.setItem("input", input);
   });
</script>
```

Ahora solo necesitas guardarlo al `localstorage` y esta listo, puedes recuperarlo de  ahi con `localStorage.getItem('input');`

te dejo la documentación por aca:

- [preventDefault](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp#:%7E:text=The%20preventDefault()%20method%20cancels,link%20from%20following%20the%20URL)
- [Convenciones de nombres en los id](https://yeonjuan.github.io/html-eslint/docs/rules/id-naming-convention/)

te hago una recomendación, los ids no los coloques con mayúscula inicial

Comment: gracias voy a revisarlo

Comment: No olvides valorar la respuesta si te fue de utilidad.

Comment: Ahorita lo estaba revisando, pero en realidad no qusiera usar `preventDefault` ya que si quisiera mande a otra pagina despues en hacer submit al form. Entonces mas bien como decia en la consulta es que aunque se cambie de pagina y despues vuelva nuevamente a este form, pues que los datos que se ingresaron en principio sigan ahi.

Comment: Puedes hacer la redirección igual aun con el prevent default, ¿te sirve?

Comment: Y como se haria  en ese caso ya que prevent default evita la redireccion del form?

Comment: Cuando haces la redirección que proceso llevas a cabo o solo cambias de vista y obtienes la data por localstorage?